# get offset of the textnode instead of element node

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I read [a document](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level-2-Range-Position).
According to which when I select the whole node from `<p>` tag to `</p>` tag it gives an offset of the element node (`startoffset = 0` and `endOffSet = 4`). However, I want the `startOffset` and `endOffSet` of the textnode, which means that `startOffSet` of first textnode would be `0` and `endOffset` would be the length of the last textnode.

```
<p>
    <cdl:metadata pagenumber="1" >Bull World Health Organ</cdl:metadata>
    <cdl:metadata pagenumber="1" > 2010;88:887&#x2013;896G </cdl:metadata>
    <cdl:metadata pagenumber="1">|</cdl:metadata>
    <cdl:metadata pagenumber="1" > doi:10.2471/BLT.09.071852</cdl:metadata>
</p>
```

Comment: Do you want to have this in CKEditor (your tag) or in plain `contenteditable`?

Comment: BTW. What's your question? I guess that you want to transform one range into another, right? You should make it clear.

Comment: i want it ckeditor tag and fckeditor tag

Comment: i am getting range of element node but i want range of text node. I used given code in order to get offset var startOffSet=range.startOffset;
var endOffSet = range.endOffset;